# copy file from host to vagrant virtual machine

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, vagrantfile

I am new with virtual machine. I want to copy a file from host (Mac) to vagrant virtual machine. I could not share a folder, so I want to use command line. How can I copy a file from host to vagrant virtual machine with command line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To copy a file from the host to vagrant:

```
scp -P 2222 /path/to/file vagrant@127.0.0.1:.
```

- By default The vagrant instance uses port 2222 and ip 127.0.0.1. The password for vagrant is 'vagrant'.
  The file will be copied to the home of vagrant.

To copy a file from vagrant to host machine:

```
scp -P 2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1:/path/to/file
```

Comment: This is outdated. Ports and IP addresses aren't generally valid. I recommend @gavenkoa's answer.If you want to use ssh,  `vagrant ssh --no-tty -- cat '>' '$DST' < "$SRC"` doesn't require knowledge of ports, IP addresses, or passwords.

Answer (score 4):

one easy way is to let vagrant handles the copy through the [File Provisioner](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/file.html) :

```
config.vm.provision "file", source: "~/.gitconfig", destination: ".gitconfig"
```

If you really want to use a command line, it might be dependant on your VM, assuming you have linux based VM, you could use scp and copy the file through ssh. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106482

Answer (score 4):

There is an officially supported command [vagrant upload](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/upload.html):

```
vagrant upload source [destination] [name|id]
```

Comment: definitely the easiest way to do it